# has_many of the same table through several others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations

What am trying to do is:
i have a User model and i have a Task model
Task has 2 types of users Owners and Supervisors all of them are users !

so what i have so far is:

Task Model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_owners, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :task_supervisors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :task_owners
  has_many :users, through: :task_supervisors
end
```

TaskSupervisor Model

```
class TaskSupervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

TaskOwner Model

```
class TaskOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and finally the User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_owners
  has_many :task_supervisors
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_owners
  has_many :tasks, through: :task_supervisors
end
```

now as you can imagine ... my problem is when i get a task and retrieve the users i only get one of my associations ... what i need is a way to change the getters name or identify them some how basically to be able to say something like

```
task.owners
task.supervisors
```

Comment: Why do you have this twice? `has_many :users, through: :task_owners`. Also the `User` model should have: `has_many :tasks` (plural of task)

Comment: @TheChamp sorry ... copy paste issuue ... i clean that right away

Comment: as for the has_many tasks well that was a genuine error :)

Comment: Could you describe the issue a bit more? I don't understand what you mean by "you only retrieve one of your associations". Isn't that expected when you call `task.task_owners`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_owners, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :task_supervisors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owners, through: :task_owners, source: :users
  has_many :supervisors, through: :task_supervisors, source: :users
end
```

You should be able to do this.

Then you should get your `task.owners` and `task.supervisors`

Edit:

You will need to change your user model to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_owners
  has_many :task_supervisors
  has_many :owned_tasks, through: :task_owners, source: :tasks
  has_many :supervised_tasks, through: :task_supervisors, source: :tasks
end
```

Comment: + 1 like this one. ;) Small typo: *to* instead of *too*

Comment: i get this when i implement your solution ... but i think it's the thing i was looking for anyway

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :owner or :owners in model TaskOwner. Try 'has_many :owners, :through => :task_owners, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :task or :user?

Comment: i'll google around ... if i can fix it i'll definitely choose your answer as The one"

Comment: @KarimMagdyMansour updated, just tag on source and it should work.  Not sure if `class_name` is necessary due to specifying source, i suspect not.

Comment: I'll remove that bit then